# how to add style dynamically in ie8

Tags: jquery, css, internet-explorer-8

I have append style tag dynamically using following code,

```
$("<style id=highlightSegment type='text/css'> .highlightStyle{ fill:red;stroke:black;}</style>").appendTo("body");
```

it was working in chrome, firefox and IE10.. but it was not working in IE8.

how to resolve and how to achieve this in IE8

Comment: `style` elements should be appended to the `head`

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan ok but that's not a problem

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan also i have changed head instead of body still also not working